# Processes synchronisation swift on OSX

Tags: swift, macos, process, synchronization

I need some synchronisation among multiple processes, something like POSIX semaphores or a shared serial dispatch queue. Is there something similar for swift in OS X.

Comment: `sem_open()` and friends seems to be available in Swift, did you try to use it?

Comment: I missed them I just skimmed through docs. Can you post an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named semaphores are available in Swift:

```
import Darwin

var sema = sem_open("/mysema", O_CREAT, 0o666, 0)
guard sema != SEM_FAILED else {
    perror("sem_open")
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

defer { sem_close(sema) }

print("Waiting for semaphore")
sem_wait(sema)
print("Got semaphore")
```

Answer (score 0):

**As Martin R pointed out, this works between threads, not processes.**

Yes, sure, you [should read](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) about the Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). Or [here](http://www.brilliantraven.com/code-snippets/grand-central-dispatch.html).

A good video for it is [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/) at WWDC.

Here is an example about semaphores taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/ymyzk/808f72d55bdf0432077b):

```
private func semaphoreExample2() {
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(queue) {
        NSLog("Running async task...")
        sleep(3)
        NSLog("Async task completed")
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    NSLog("Waiting async task...")
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    NSLog("Continue!")
}
```

Or another one in Swift 3 from [here](http://www.brilliantraven.com/code-snippets/grand-central-dispatch.html):

```
// creating the semaphore with a resource count of 1
let semaphore       = DispatchSemaphore( value: 1 )
let watchdogTime    = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(1)
...

// synchronize access to a shared resource using the semaphore
if case .TimedOut = semaphore.wait(timeout: watchdogTime) {
    print("OMG! Someone was bogarting that semaphore!")
}
// begin access shared resource…
...

// end access to resource
semaphore.signal()
```

Comment: Can a GCD semaphore be shared between different *processes*?

Comment: Missed the "between processes" part :-(